# An inequality involving binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Let $t \leq s \in \mathbb{N}$, and $0 \leq p \leq s$ be an integer. Then, $p \choose t$ + $s-p \choose t$ $\leq$ $s \choose t$.

Any idea how to proceed? I tried expanding out everything, but it didnt work.

Note: $n\choose r$ = $0$ if $n<r$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let there are $s$ balls: $\{1,\ldots,p,p+1,\ldots,s\}$. Number of ways to choose $t$ balls from $\{1,\ldots,p\}$ or from $\{p+1,\ldots,s\}$ is less than or equal to number of ways to choose $t$ balls from $\{1,\ldots,p,p+1,\ldots,s\}$.

Now, Number of ways to choose $t$ balls from $\{1,\ldots,p\}$ or from $\{p+1,\ldots,s\}$ is equal to $p \choose t$ + $s-p \choose t$, and number of ways to choose $t$ balls from $\{1,\ldots,p,p+1,\ldots,s\}$ is equal to $s \choose t$.

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the [Chu Vandermonde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) identity:

$$\sum_{j=0}^t\binom{p}{j}\binom{s-p}{t-j}=\binom{s}{t},$$

since at $j=0$ and $j=t$, you have terms:

$$\binom{p}{t}+\binom{s-p}{t}=\binom{p}{0}\binom{s-p}{t}+\binom{p}{t}\binom{s-p}{0}\leq \binom{s}{t}.$$

You can easily prove the identity (or really just your subclass of it) by considering the expansion of both sides of: $(1+x)^{p}(1+x)^{s-p}=(1+x)^{s}.$ and matching comparing powers of $x^m$.